# Passing integer variable from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page where there are two variables which are flag variables....I want to pass these variables to a servlet. How should I pass these variables to a servlet?

This is my jsp page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Student Registration Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
h3{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 22pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; color:SlateBlue;
text-align: center; text-decoration: underline }
table{font-family: Calibri; color:white; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal;
text-align:; background-color: SlateBlue; border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid navy}
table.inner{border: 0px}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Create Category</h3>
<form action="insert_category" method="POST">

<table align="center" cellpadding = "10">

<tr>
<td>Category Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="category_name" maxlength="30"/>
(max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
</td>
</tr>


    <%
int flag=1;
int operation=1;
request.setAttribute("flag", String.valueOf(flag));
request.setAttribute("operation", String.valueOf(operation));
%>

<tr>
<td>Category Code</td>
<td><input type="text" name="category_code" maxlength="30"/>
(max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
package com.kunal.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CreateCategory
 */
@WebServlet("/CreateCategory")
public class InsertCategory extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public InsertCategory() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String category__name=request.getParameter("category_name");
        String category_code=request.getParameter("category_code");
        int flag=(int)request.getAttribute("flag");
        int operation=(int)request.getAttribute("operation");
        if(flag==1 && operation==1)
        {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agro";

        Connection connection = null;
        long catcode=Integer.parseInt(category_code);
        try {
            // Load the database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Get a Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
            //Add the data into the database

            //String sql = "insert into sample values(?,?)";

            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into tbl_category VALUES(?,?,?)");

            pst.setString(1,null);
            pst.setString(2,category__name);
            pst.setLong(3,catcode);

            int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();
            if(numRowsChanged!=0){
                System.out.println("Successfull execution");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("adminhome.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
            else{
                            System.err.println("Problem with the insertion query");
            }
            pst.close();
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
            // Always close the database connection.
            try {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot use getParameters() method because these are simply two variables. Is there any way to pass these to servlet? I am getting a NullPointerException

StackTrace

```
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Agro' did not find a matching property.
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 673 ms
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 675 ms
Aug 12, 2014 1:22:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [InsertServlet] in context with path [/Agro] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kunal.servlet.InsertCategory.doPost(InsertCategory.java:42)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Only form submit or ajax. Remember, it's the client side!

Comment: why you can't use `getParamter()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to passed `flag` and `operation` parameter at the time of form submit than you can store it in hidden field, so that when you submit form it will send with your form parameter.

```
<form action="insert_category">
    <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="1">  

    ....rest of your code  

</form>
```

at server side you get this parameter by `request.getParameter()` like below :

```
int flag=(int)request.getParameter("flag");
int operation=(int)request.getParameter("operation");
```

OR
you may store this parameter in `session` and get value from session on server side for example :

in you JSP :

```
        <%                          
            session.setAttribute("flag", String.valueOf(flag));
            session.setAttribute("operation", String.valueOf(operation));
        %>
```

On server side in servlet :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
int flag=(int)session.getAttribute("flag");
int operation=(int)session.getAttribute("operation");
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `include` or `import` a Servlet in the JSP and pass the values as request parameters.

Try to avoid Scriplet instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

JSP:

```
<jsp:include page="/myServlet?flag=1&operation=1"/>
```

OR

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:import url="/myServlet?flag=1&operation=1"/>
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(request.getParameter("flag"));
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("operation"));
}
```

---

If you are using form then it should be

```
<form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/insert_category"
```

---

OR set it in `request` attribute

JSP:

```
<c:set var="flag" value="1" scope="request"/>
<c:set var="operation" value="1" scope="request"/>
<c:import url="/test2"/>
```

Setvlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("flag"));
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("operation"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options like request scope, session scope etc
try something like this

```
request.setAttribute("flag", flag);
request.setAttribute("operation", operation);
```

And get the attributes like this

```
int flag = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("flag"));
int operation = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("operation"));
```

Similarly you can use `session` object to set and get attributes

Edit: your form action url is `insert_category` so change

```
@WebServlet("/CreateCategory")
```

to

```
@WebServlet("/insert_category")
```

and as you are using annotation based url mapping I hope you dont have the mapping in `web.xml`

Comment: how to send these attribute to the servlet?

Comment: in form have an action button to redirect to the servlet on submit

Comment: I used it but it is givin a NullPointerException