# Sending a variable to a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing, httpserver

I want to pass a variable to servlet, using a form in a jsp file:

```
<form action="userSrevlet">
    <input name="username" type="hidden" value="<%=username%>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="User"/>
</form>
```

However I get

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP
```

error after adding the value of the variable that way. How can I send it?

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: You have correct syntax, so the issue must be from outside of the code you posted. Btw you can also use `value="${username}"` to do that.

Comment: refer following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258613/passing-integer-variable-from-jsp-to-servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be getting error due missing value for username i.e. username variable is not found or set. Better way is to use EL i.e. ${username} which will take set value="" if username is not found.